# A series with the non square free numbers $q_n:\:$ $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{1+\Omega(q_k)}}{q_k}=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

Let $q_n$ be the $n$-th natural number that can be divided by a square $>1$ (https://oeis.org/A013929). Conjecture: 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{1+\Omega(q_k)}}{q_k}=0$$
where $\Omega(n)$ is the number of (not necessarily different) prime factors of $n$.

I'm sure that the conjecture is true, but I can't prove it and that's what I need help with.

The conjecture is related with [An accountancy of the natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1899443/an-accountancy-of-the-natural-numbers). The corresponding series for squarefree numbers $s_n$
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{1+\Omega(s_k)}}{s_k}=1$$

Comment: @user243301: I'm certainly not an expert of anything. Math and especially number theory is far to complicated for me. But I like good ideas and never forget a good idea. Thanks for the video tip, I think I will put my computational system BigZ http://forthmath.blogspot.se/ on the abc.

Comment: Okey I am saying previous words because I had the idea that your have much more knowledges in algebra and geometry. About (I hope that my words are the rights) polynomials and integers there is the following empirical phenomenon (prime divisors are the same as prime factors of polynomials):  is one has a proposition about polynomials then should be a similar propositon/question about integers, and the same if one has a proposition on integers one should be find a counterpart for polynomials. Sorry and thanks.

Comment: I don't know why you are sorry. If you see something in this or any of my questions that can be generalized or reformulized the way you suggests, I would be glad if you posted a question about it. I know about polynomial rings and I studied algebraical geometry + algebraical topology 35 years ago, but I never toke a single lesson on number theory. $\overset{..}{\smile}$.

Comment: I said sorry, because I dont' want disturb with my comments, the right is always provide a contribution of the current question/post. On the other hand since I know that you are interesting in polynomials and square free integers I recommend the divulgative paper written by **Granville** and **Tucker**, *It's As Easy As abc*, from NOTICES OF THE AMS,  VOLUME 49, NUMBER 10, you can find it in Google because there is open access, I like the **trick** quoted in the last words  before the section **Oesterlé and Masser’s abc-conjecture.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This must be due to the fact that the reciprocals of all squarefree numbers with whatever signs appear in the $\prod\left(1\pm{1\over p}\right)$, and the reciprocals of all natural numbers appear in another product, $\prod{1\over1\pm{1/p}}$, and both products are easy to evaluate.

Indeed,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(-1)^{\Omega(n)}\over n}=\prod_{prime\;p}\left(1-{1\over p}+{1\over p^2}-{1\over p^3}+\dots\right)={1\over\prod\left(1+{1\over p}\right)}=0$$

On the other hand, look at the similar sum over squarefree numbers:
$$\sum_{squarefree\;s}{(-1)^{\Omega(s)}\over s}=\prod_{prime\;p}\left(1-{1\over p}\right)=0$$

Your sum over squareful numbers is just the difference between the two.

Comment: While I think this is a great insightful solution, there is a need of justifying infinite sum = infinite product.

Comment: Sure, that would require certain gymnastics, especially as the sums are only _conditionally_ convergent.

Comment: Well, not very much of gymnastics. The arguments are standard in analytic number theory, using Dirichlet series, zero-free region, Perron's formula (using complex analysis), etc.